# Separating sender in MailMessage Class ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, email

I have this method that will send Email to people according to my SQL SELECT, it works like this:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TITLE, RECIPIENT, SENDER FROM DAY2, CADUSER WHERE CADUSER.ID = ID_CADUSER", con))
{
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        sb.AppendLine(reader["TITLE"].ToString());
        st.AppendLine(reader["RECIPIENT"].ToString());
        se.AppendLine(reader["SENDER"].ToString());
    }
}
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("mysmtp.com", 25);
smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("______", "______");
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

try
{
    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(se.ToString(), st.ToString());
    mailMessage.Subject = "New Documents";
    mailMessage.Body = "The documents are: \n" + sb.ToString();
    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{

}
```

The problem is that when I have more than 1 sender or recipient, It won't work because AppendLine command will join every result from my select in just one line like this: test@gmail.comtest2@gmail.com making it impossible to send.

How can I separate one Email address by one to correct this issue? Thought about making a While routine but I don't know.

Comment: Where do you set Sender or recipient on on SmtpClient?

Comment: @PankajKapare  MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(se.ToString(), st.ToString()); The first one is sender, the second one is recipient.

Answer (score 1):

In brief, try this:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();

List<string> To = new List<string>();
To.Add("email1@gmail.com");
To.Add("email1@gmail.com");

foreach (var item in To)
{
     mail.To.Add(to);
}

SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage?view=netframework-4.7.2) out, there are many attributes to help you.

I hope this helps